# Service __len__ not found Unexpected error, recovered safely

Tags: google-ads-api

**python3.8**

**My code:**

```
from googleads import adwords

def execute_request():
    adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage(path="google_general/googleads.yaml")
    campaign_service = adwords_client.GetService('CampaignService', version='v201809')
    pass


context["dict_list"] = execute_request()
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/pycharm-community-2019.3.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_xml.py", line 282, in frame_vars_to_xml
    xml += var_to_xml(v, str(k), evaluate_full_value=eval_full_val)
  File "/home/michael/pycharm-community-2019.3.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_xml.py", line 369, in var_to_xml
    elif hasattr(v, "__len__") and not is_string(v):
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleads/common.py", line 694, in __getattr__
    raise googleads.errors.GoogleAdsValueError('Service %s not found' % attr)
googleads.errors.GoogleAdsValueError: Service __len__ not found
Unexpected error, recovered safely.
```

**googleads.yaml about logging**

```
logging:
  version: 1
  disable_existing_loggers: False
  formatters:
    default_fmt:
      format: ext://googleads.util.LOGGER_FORMAT
    handlers:
      default_handler:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        formatter: default_fmt
        level: DEBUG
    loggers:
    # Configure root logger
      "":
      handlers: [default_handler]
      level: DEBUG
```

I've just started studying the API. 
Namely, I'm trying to execute my first request (https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call#make_your_first_api_call)

Could you help me with this problem? At least how to localize it more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem which results from the way the PyCharm debugger inspects live objects during debugging.

Specifically, it checks if a given object has the `__len__` attribute/method in the code of `var_to_xml`, most likely to determine an appropriate representation of the object for the debugger interface (which seems to require constructing an XML representation).

`googleads` service objects such as your `campaign_service`, however, use some magic to be able to call the defined SOAP methods on them without requiring to hard-code all of them. The code looks like this:

```python
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    """Support service.method() syntax."""
    if self._WsdlHasMethod(attr):
      if attr not in self._method_proxies:
        self._method_proxies[attr] = self._CreateMethod(attr)
      return self._method_proxies[attr]
    else:
      raise googleads.errors.GoogleAdsValueError('Service %s not found' % attr)
```

This means that the debugger's check for a potential `__len__` attribute is intercepted, and because the [CampaignService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/CampaignService) does not have a SOAP operation called `__len__`, an exception is raised.

You can validate this by running your snippet in the regular way (i.e. not debugging it) and checking if that works.

An actual fix would seem to either require that PyCharm's debugger changes the way it inspects objects (not calling `hasattr(v, "__len__")`) or that `googleads` modifies the way it implements `__getattr__`, for example by actually implementing a `__len__` method that just raises `AttributeError`.

Comment: Hi, dorian. Thank you for your great answer. But what IDE do you recommend to use instead of PyCharm?

Comment: Corresponding ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39954 Workaround is to edit the debugger source code and wrap the problematic place with try/except till the next update https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39954#focus=streamItem-27-3927753.0-0

Comment: @Michael, I use PyCharm myself. The fact that JetBrains cared enough to directly comment here validates that choice :)